# Angular2 - Get URL of error in Observable ForkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs5, fork-join, angular2-observables

I have an Angular2 ForkJoin that can contain multiple HTTP requests.  When the ForkJoin errors, I'd like to be able to determine the sub domain/domain of the URL of the request in the ForkJoin that caused the error.  If the error is a 401 Unauthorized, then I need to try and re-establish a new connection.  I need the sub domain/domain of the failed request so I can look up the credentials in order to re-establish a token then attempt the ForkJoin request again.  My ForkJoin could be making multiple requests to different domains.

```js
   return Observable.create(observer => 
   {
    //JOIN ALL REQUESTS TOGETHER INTO A BATCH TO BE FORKED....
    let observableBatch = []; 

    //ADD OBSERVABLE FOR SINGLE GET REQUEST    
    if (requestModel.Get)
    {
     observableBatch.push(this.HttpGet(requestModel.Get));
    } 

    //ADD OBSERVABLE FOR AN ARRAY OF GET REQUESTS    
    if (requestModel.GetList)
    {
     for (let item in requestModel.GetList) 
     {
      observableBatch.push(this.HttpGet(requestModel.GetList[ item ]));
     }
    } 
        
    //ADD OBSERVABLE FOR SINGLE POST REQUEST 
    if (requestModel.Post)
    {
     observableBatch.push(this.HttpPost(requestModel.Post));
    }    
        
    //ADD OBSERVABLE FOR AN ARRAY OF POST REQUESTS
    if (requestModel.PostList)
    {
     for (let item in requestModel.PostList) 
     {
      observableBatch.push(this.HttpPost(requestModel.PostList[ item ]));
     }     
    } 
    
    /*
    FORK JOIN RETURNS AN ARRAY OF RESULT SETS (1 FOR EACH REQUEST IN FORK JOIN)
    THIS OBSERVABLE, IF SUCCESSFUL, RETURNS THE FOLLOWING:
    [1..N] - THE RAW JSON FROM CMS SERVICE
    */
    let forkJoinSubscription = Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch)
     .subscribe (
      //SUCCESS, WE HAVE JSON RESPONSE(S)
      data =>
      {      
       console.log('FORK JOIN SUCCESS !!!', data);       
      },
     
      //ERROR
      err =>
      {
       console.log('FORK JOIN ERROR...', err);
      },

      //COMPLETE
      () =>
      {
       if (forkJoinSubscription)
       { 
        forkJoinSubscription.unsubscribe();
       }       
       //console.log('FORK JOIN COMPELETED');
      }
    );   
   });
```

Is it possible to determine the subdomain/domain of the URL in the batch of URLS in ForkJoin when an error happens?